# How can i store the result of verifyElementPresent ie either true/false in a variable, for further use?

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to use the result for further conditional purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code. you will get "true" or "false" value in "check" variable for further use.

```
<tr>
    <td>storeTextPresent</td>
    <td>How can i store the result of verifyElementPresent ie either true/false in a variable, for further use?</td>
    <td>check</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>getEval</td>
    <td>alert(${check})</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for the above knowledge, but i wanted to it for verifyElementPresent.

Comment: This is the way to use store result..Output will be the same for  storeElementPresent  and verifyElementPresent.

Comment: I checked for verifyElementPresent the result is not getting stored, for storeElementPresent  its working.

Comment: Yes, with verifyElementPresent command you can not store true or false result.. So only with storeElementPresent command you can use stored result value.

Comment: So the conclusion is the result cannot be stored with verifyElementPresent

Answer (score 0):

Use 'storeelementpresent' command and store the value in variable and assert the variable value by using 'gotoif' if you intend to use in conditions.

Comment: Those commands are not part of Selenium IDE. You need to install the Flow Control plugin to use them